# Devexpress Xtragrid export issue

Tags: excel, xtragrid

In have two datagrids that am exporting to excel with the code below

```
        PrintableComponentLink pcl1 = new PrintableComponentLink(printingSystem1);
        PrintableComponentLink pcl2 = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());

        pcl1.Component = gridControl1;
        pcl2.Component = gridControl2;

        pcl1.CreateDocument();
        pcl2.CreateDocument();

        printingSystem1.Document.Pages.AddRange(pcl2.PrintingSystem.Document.Pages);

        XlsxExportOptions ept = new XlsxExportOptions();

        ept.ExportMode = XlsxExportMode.SingleFilePageByPage;

        string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\..\..\" + "All.xlsx";

        printingSystem1.ExportToXlsx(path, ept);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

The problem is that it exports 40 rows per sheet. That means it creates very many excel sheets in the workbook. How can i make it export more than 40 rows per sheet?
It is strange behaviour because excel accepts more than 1 million rows per sheet

Comment: Kindly assist with excel export

Comment: I need some help guys

Comment: XlsxExportMode.SingleFilePageByPage... should be a giveaway I think